# Python Twisted Maximum Number Of Active Connections

Tags: python, networking, client-server, twisted

I am writing a simple program that sends messages back and forth between a single computer running many clients and multiple servers using Twisted.  Replies to these messages require fairly long calculations, which is why I implemented `deferToThread()` and `Callback()` on both the client and the server as to not block messages from coming in.

However, I would like to maximize the number of simultaneous active connections that can be handled concurrently.  I think, as it stands now, my program can handle 10 simultaneous active connections (as in 10 threads performing a calculation for a reply on either the client or the server).  Does it make sense that this is the default number of active connections and can I increase it using the `suggestThreadPoolSize()` option for the reactor as described [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/core/howto/threading.html)?

Comment: Are you bottlenecked by processing (CPU bound, requests queuing up) or by networking (connection open/closes)? Having more threads than the number of cores is generally unwise, but I don't really understand your problem properly.

Comment: My question can be generalized to: What does the `suggestThreadPoolSize()` option do?

Comment: `suggestThreadPoolSize()` just changes the maximum number of concurrent threads.  Your question, however, isn't what you think - you shouldn't be using that option, because it's only really relevant for I/O bound operations in threads (such as the ones that you need to do with 3rd-party database drivers, or hostname resolution).  See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your program is CPU-bound, then the Python [global interpreter lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) will prevent you from having any multi-CPU concurrency, so fiddling with the thread pool size will not have much practical effect on the speed with which your program can deal with new connections.

Instead, you should use [`reactor.spawnProcess`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorProcess.spawnProcess.html) to start a subprocess, and shuttle your CPU-intensive work off to a pool of subprocesses.  Something such as [Ampoule](https://launchpad.net/ampoule) might help you do this more conveniently.

However, even multiple processes will only buy you as much CPU concurrency as you have ... CPUs.  (Well, cores, or hyperthreads, really; but, "logical" CPUs, at least.)   Accepting more work when you do not have the available resources to actually *do* that work is going to build up huge buffers in memory and eventually crash your program.  Eventually you need to [apply backpressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_pressure#Back_pressure_in_information_technology).

Twisted does provide [all the tools you need](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/producers.html) to do this right now, although we are working on making it [even easier](http://tm.tl/1956).

Oh - and this should go without saying, but if your program *isn't* CPU-bound, then you should just stop using threads ;-).